# detecting lines in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, line

I am trying to detect the number of white lines in this image:

[image: test image]

I have tried using the code from the following link: [How to calculate the number of lines of text in an image in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706254/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-lines-of-text-in-an-image-in-matlab)

```
RGB = imread('test image.jpg');
GSC = rgb2gray(RGB);
BW = imbinarize(GSC);
figure
imshowpair(GSC,BW,'montage')
se = strel('line',size(BW,2),0);
out = imdilate(BW,se);
[~,num] = bwlabel(out);
```

However, the number of white lines I am detecting is not the right number.  The value I get for the total number of lines is 1.

Comment: Is the correct answer 5 or 9?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I would say 9.... I sure hope it is given my answer lol.  If it's 5, that's a matter of doing a bit more post-processing.

Comment: @MarkSetchell eh, I decided to tackle both cases. Thanks for the motivation!

Comment: @rayryeng thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: @MauriceMoh You're very welcome.  Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the original author of the post that you have referenced.  Please note that the question and the subsequent answer is designed for detecting **lines of text** in the image.  Your image does not contain text so it will obviously not work out of box.  In the future when you are using code, please read and ensure that you are using it the way it is intended to be used.

Specifically, when you use my method out of box with your image, the entire background is white so you need to eliminate the background.  If you don't, then the lines and the background count as one object and so that's why you only get 1 object counted.  As an example, this is what you get when you binarize the image without any processing:

[image]

That's not a good representation of the image.  Note that in the link you provided, the background and text was very simple.  The text was completely white with the text completely black.  You have a somewhat more complicated background.  The background is gray while some of the object is black with some white lines throughout the object.  One thing that I found useful to solve your problem was to play around with the thresholding of the image.  I chose 0.9 to remove the background as well as the background of the object to leave the lines intact.  I used [`im2bw`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html) from versions before MATLAB R2016a.  [`imbinarize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imbinarize.html) is part of R2016a and up but you should be able to swap between the two methods.  I'll directly reference your image from Stack Overflow to make this reproducible:

```
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKd4V.jpg');
BW = im2bw(rgb2gray(im), 0.9); % or BW = imbinarize(rgb2gray(im), 0.9);
figure; imshow(BW);
```

We now get this image:

[image]

That's much better.  Because you already have lines in the image, this makes the problem ridiculously simple.  The post you have linked finds the total number of lines in text which is why the dilation with a line element that spans the width of the image is required.  You already have lines so this dilation is not necessary.  As such, just count how many non-zero regions there are in this image and you're done:

```
[~,num] = bwlabel(BW);
```

And we see that there are:

```
>> num

num =

     9
```

Though you haven't specified, if the lines on the left and right side need to be joined (i.e. in your case, there are 5 lines instead of 9), you can certainly use the dilation logic from the link you provided to merge the lines together.  In this case, you will want to make the vertical extent of the structuring element thicker.  The reason why is because the lines on the left and right side have a slight vertical offset so specifying a larger vertical extent will ensure that the lines get joined when you dilate.  Therefore, instead of a line make a rectangular box that spans the width of the image. I arbitrarily chose a height of 5 pixels here:

```
se = strel('rectangle', [5, size(BW, 2)]);
out = imdilate(BW, se);
```

We now get this image:

[image]

That looks pretty nice.... and now if you count how many lines there are:

```
>> [~,num] = bwlabel(out)

num = 

     5
```

Comment: Excellent - another top quality analysis and solution!

Comment: @rayryeng Since you talk about rectangular structuring element can you please give some insights about what kind of element and what type of morphological ops should be considered to make black thick lines (horizontal and vertical) disappear or extracted in this image [line_grid](https://imgur.com/a/12sQfr8) while other info remain intact? I tried basic erosion but it adds noise. I tried your approach of line element of the size of image width but there exist so many different sizes of lines segments which connect symbols. I need to filter lines based on their thickness.

Comment: @SKR please ask a new question. This is not appropriate as a comment.

Comment: @rayryeng Sure, thanks for the direction. I am putting up there.

Comment: @rayryeng The question has been re-phrased and re-structured at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53294066/5396082).