# General approach for extracting specific lines or line segments in an image

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, image-morphology

I have this sample cropped image:

[image]

I need to make black thick lines (horizontal and vertical) disappear or extracted while leave all other info intact. These specific lines are either 4 or 5 pixels thick. I tried:

1. Simple filtering of rows having more zeros/ones if image is read as NumPy array but the filtering condition doesn't terminate till a single row is left with zero or one.
2. Erosion with simple kernel (3,3) but it leaves some noise because some symbols are also thick black
3. Dilation with line structuring element of the width of image width but there are overwhelming variations on line segments' sizes connecting different symbols that the basic info about each small line segment is lost.

Can someone give insights or directions about what kind of structuring elements, what type of morphological ops should be considered or may be any other clever heuristics? The output, if *extraction of thick black lines is done*, will then look like this grid of random line segments:
[image]

Comment: The "thick black lines" you speak of... They appear to have a height or width that's higher than the other lines, yes?

Comment: You should look into Hough transformation - after erosion, it is probably possible to detect the straight lines left

Comment: what about erosion, followed by lineSegmentDetector? The noise should hopefully not build up line segments?

Comment: An ideal solution as picture would be helpful, otherwise e.g. "thick horizontal line" is ambiguous.

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, you are right but let me explain. I would rather say black thick lines and line segments (because symbols are inserted on lines at random positions). For horizontal lines, yes their height is 4 or 5 pixels thick which is higher than all other lines but for widths there are huge variations so it is difficult to say higher than the other lines in terms of width. Similar facts apply analogously to vertical lines or line segments. Do you intend to filter them through some special structuring element?

Comment: @TA Lines or line segments are either 5 or 4 pixels thick so after erosion there are some other not useful lines remain or some part of black symbols remain. When I apply Hough with so many trials for its parameters for line spacing and line sizes I don't get much useful info simply because there is just so much variation in line/line segment sizes, either it will join or it will break. Do you know whether Hough or other transform where we can put the thickness constraint? But then it actually becomes a rectangle detection problem, right?

Comment: @Micka Can you tell about this lineSegmentDetector function? Yes, the noise will not build up line segments but it may if the line segment size in some image is as small as any other symbol's edge. Also, after erosion there are still some not useful lines, if they are removed too then some relevant lines are lost too.

Comment: I think the expected output would be desirable... Or else we are all going to propose solutions that may not be what you want. Please update your question to provide what the expected output is.

Comment: @Vroomfondel One of the expected output can be like shown in the updated question above. Basically, I manually removed everything but the thick lines or line segments. I hope it is now clear that there are several line segments which make it a little challenging.

Comment: @rayryeng I updated the question which now includes the expected output. Several small line segments can now be seen clearly.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you erode the image and extract hough lines:

```
I=rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbHFL.jpg'));

Ibw=I>200;

imshow(Ibw)
SE=strel('disk',1)
Ier=imerode(~Ibw,SE);

[H,T,R] = hough(Ier);
P  = houghpeaks(H,100,'threshold',ceil(0.1*max(H(:))));

lines = houghlines(Ier,T,R,P);

%% plot
imshow(I);hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','blue');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
      xy_long = xy;
   end
end
```

From here, you can start thinking on what to delete. This is not straightforward unless you have a dictionary of symbols, e.g. how do you delete the line around the structures with `>-<` shape? do you delete all the middle pixels or do you keep the entire middle thin bar? You can only know this if you know how the symbol should be without the thick lines.

[image]

Comment: I used Hough Lines transform but due to the thickness of black lines there were many small lines detected in one big line and it was difficult to control through the parameters. I have a few questions: 1) why erode with a disk element of size 1? 2) Why not erode with rectangular element? 3) The green line seems to pass over the symbols whereas in the input image black line never crosses any symbol, actually we have to consider them as line segments before and after any symbol. 4) are the blue cross beginning and red cross end of a single line? 5) one small segment in bottom was not detected.

Comment: @SKR 1)empirical  test showed good result, didnt think of it more. 2) same as 1. 3) The last paragraph is about that. This is not a full solution to your huge project, just a starting point. Your question is too big to answer in SO entirely. People get paid to solve this type of problems. 4) yes, check the code 5) Yes